# Detect freed object called with TThread.ForceQueue() with delay

Tags: delphi

When you are in a `TFrame` and you do `TThread.ForceQueue(nil, MyFrame.OneProc, 200)` how can you check in the `MyFrame.OneProc` procedure  that `MyFrame` was not destroyed in the mean time?

In other words, what mechanism can be used in such common scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *guardian* interface that will be fully functioning instance you can use to check whether guarded object is released in the meantime.

```
type
  IGuardian = interface
    function GetIsDismantled: Boolean;
    procedure Dismantle;
    property IsDismantled: Boolean read GetIsDismantled;
  end;

  TGuardian = class(TInterfacedObject, IGuardian)
  private
    FIsDismantled: Boolean;
    function GetIsDismantled: Boolean;
  public
    procedure Dismantle;
    property IsDismantled: Boolean read GetIsDismantled;
  end;


procedure TGuardian.Dismantle;
begin
  FIsDismantled := True;
end;

function TGuardian.GetIsDismantled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FIsDismantled;
end;
```

And then you need to add guardian field in your frame

```
type
  TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
  private
    FGuardian: IGuardian;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Guardian: IGuardian read FGuardian;
  end;

constructor TMyFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FGuardian := TGuardian.Create;
end;

destructor TMyFrame.Destroy;
begin
  // prevent AV when destroying partially
  // constructed instance
  if Assigned(FGuardian) then
    FGuardian.Dismantle;
  inherited;
end;
```

But you cannot directly queue frame's `MyProc`, you need to use anonymous methods and capture that guardian variable so its life will be extended beyond the lifetime of the frame.

Reference counting will keep the guardian object instance alive even after `MyFrame` is released and its memory will be automatically managed.

It is important to use locally declared `Guardian` interface variable and capture that variable instead of directly capturing `MyFrame.Guardian` field because that field address will no longer be valid after `MyFrame` is released.

```
procedure CallMyProc;
var
  Guardian: IGuardian;
begin
  Guardian := MyFrame.Guardian;
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil, 
    procedure
    begin
      if Guardian.IsDismantled then
        Exit;
      MyFrame.OneProc;
    end, 200);
end;
```

---

Note: Even if you use `TThread.Queue` without a delay, it is possible that frame will be released before queued procedure runs. So you need to protect your frame is such scenarios, too.

Comment: thanks Dalija ! that an idea :) I like it, seam good !

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can't call a method on an object that has been destroyed. The *preferred* solution is to simply remove the method from the queue if it hasn't been called yet, *before* destroying the object. `TThread` has a [`RemoveQueuedEvents()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.RemoveQueuedEvents) method for exactly that purpose.

For example:

```pascal
TThread.ForceQueue(nil, MyFrame.OneProc, 200);
...
TThread.RemoveQueuedEvents(MyFrame.OneProc);
MyFrame.Free;
```

Alternatively, use the frame's destructor instead:

```pascal
TThread.ForceQueue(nil, MyFrame.OneProc, 200);
...

destructor TMyFrame.Destroy;
begin
  TThread.RemoveQueuedEvents(OneProc);
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: That also a very good answer, sad that I can not say that 2 answers are accepted, because dalija is good and your solutions too :(